# Virtual Box не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Что делать если не удалось открыть сессию для виртуальной машины?

Код ошибки:

> E_FAIL (0x80004005)

Пытался решить вопрос по этому руководству: 
https://ustanovkaos.ru/reshenie-problem/ne-udalos-otkryt-sessiyu-dlya-virtualnoj-mashiny.html

К сожалению, проблема осталась.
Работаю с *Virtual Box* на *Windows 11*.

И если пытаюсь установить старые версии *VBox* вижу сообщение, что они больше не поддерживаются.

Возможно есть другой способ решить проблему?  Или есть возможность для *Windows* разрешить  использование старой версии *VBox* ?

Answer (score 1):

удалось решить эту проблему выполнив команду для отключения Hyper-V:
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off